# Regexp to replace & but not < and >

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'd like to use JS (and regex?) to replace all **&** with **&amp;**, EXCEPT those **&** characters that are related to

```
&amp;gt;
```

and

```
&amp;lt;
```

Can anybody please help? :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying `&gt;` is what should not be replaced?

Comment: What have you tried? It helps if you have something to start with before asking for the answer.

Comment: @KendallFrey's answer is good. Do you mean you want to replace all `&` but not to replace `&lt;` and `&gt;`? If so, you can try this: `/&(?!lt\b|gt\b)/gi`

Comment: @KendallFrey : Yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex like:

```
&(?!amp;|gt;|lt;)
```

JS example:

```
"test &amp; &gt; &lt; and & with &foo;".replace(/&(?!amp;|gt;|lt;)/gi, "&amp;");
```

Result:

```
"test &amp; &gt; &lt; and &amp; with &amp;foo;"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution is to check for letters and a semicolon following the &

```
/&(?![A-Z]+;)/gi
```

A complete standards-compliant version that also checks for numeric codes:

```
/&(?!([A-Za-z]+|#\d+|#x[\da-fA-F]+);)/g
```